# Is it possible to set iframe with data src inner document.domain?

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, iframe

There is an iframe with plain HTML src

```
<iframe id="myIframe"></iframe>

<script>
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data) {
        $('#myIframe').attr('src', 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + data);
    }
});
</script>
```

If to check document.domain of iframe, then it will have value of '' or null.

I want to put document.domain to iframe.

Why do I want to put document.domain? In response HTML data there is angular2 app, which uses SystemJS to import config. It checks for origin and finds that it origin of iframe is different. As a result - exception.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Thanks!

*The reason I use ajax to set iframe src is that I need to set custom headers in request to iframe src url.

Comment: `document.domain` can bypass only certain Same Origin Policies: 1.Protocol, 2. Sub-domain, 3. Ports. so basically limited to the same site.

Comment: @zer00ne, the content in iframe is located within domain (site). Although after i use Ajax request and put the result as a source for iframe - SystemJs thinks that iframe is located in '' domain.

Comment: See answer and let me know if I'm close.

Answer (score 0):

It's a tunnel you'll want then:

1. Meet Same Origin Policies:

   1. Same domain (i.e. `example.com`, `domain.net`, etc...)
2. With a sub-domain tunnel, a few Same Origin Policies are bypassed:

   1. Protocol (i.e. `http://` or `https://` )
   2. Sub-domain (i.e. `sub.domain.com` , `app.domain.com`, `docs.domain.com`, etc...)
   3. Port (i.e. `example.com:80`, `example.com:8080`, `example.com:21`)
3. The Snippet must be present on both pages.

#### SNIPPET

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>Tunnel</title>
  <style>
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    /**
     * Replace $.ajax on your subdomain with a copy taken
     * from your base domain. All jQuery AJAX actions go
     * through $.ajax (i.e. $.get, $.post), so it's all good.
     */ // http://benv.ca/2011/03/07/subdomain-tunneling-with-jquery-and-document-domain/
    (function() {
      var iframe,
        onload,
        queue = [],

        // This has to be set both here and in iframe.html
        document.domain = 'example.com';

      // Back up this page's copy of $.ajax
      window.$._ajax = window.$.ajax;

      // We'll first replace $.ajax with a thin wrapper that both
      // loads our iframe tunnel and saves invocations until the
      // iframe is ready

      $.ajax = function(params) {

        if (!iframe) {

          // tunnel.html should be a bare bones html page that
          // includes a copy of jQuery, and sets document.domain
          // to 'example.com'

          iframe = $('<iframe>')
            .attr('src', 'http://example.com/tunnel.html')
            .load(onload)
            .appendTo('head')[0];
        }

        // Save calls to $.ajax, execute when we're ready
        queue.push(params);
      };

      function onload() {

        // Our prize: a version of $.ajax that can communicate safely
        // with our base domain
        window.$.ajax = iframe.contentWindow.jQuery.ajax;

        // Flush queued $.ajax calls
        $.each(queue, function(_, params) {
          $.ajax(params);
        });

        queue = null;
      }
    })();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```